# SQL: How do I count the rows of a summed column?

Tags: sql

How do I count the number of lines of a summed column?

I have built a query that will show how many items in each order, but I need to do a count of each Sum. My goal is to see how many people bought 3 items, how many bought 4, etc...

```
SELECT Orders.id, 
  sum(Quantity) AS "Box Count"
  FROM OrderLines
    INNER JOIN Orders ON OrderLines.Order_id = Orders.id
    INNER JOIN Products ON OrderLines.Product_id = Products.id
  WHERE (Products.ProductType_id = 2) AND Orders.shipdate > '10/01/2014'
GROUP BY Orders.id
```

It is returning this:

```
   id  Box Count
-----  ---------
68015          6
69660          3
70923          3
72697         13
```

I want it to return this:

```
Box Count  Total Count
---------  -----------
        3            2
        6            1
       13            1
```

Comment: did you try count(...) instead of sum(...)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a second query:

```
SELECT 
[Box Count]
,COUNT(*) AS [Total Count]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    Orders.id, 
    sum(Quantity) AS "Box Count" 
    FROM OrderLines 
    INNER JOIN Orders ON OrderLines.Order_id = Orders.id 
    INNER JOIN Products ON OrderLines.Product_id = Products.id 
    WHERE (Products.ProductType_id = 2) AND Orders.shipdate > '10/01/2014' 
    GROUP BY Orders.id
) AS InnerQuery
GROUP BY [Box Count]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC -- optional
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.